# Custom columns of Google Ads in BigQuery through data transfer

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I want to store some Google Ads data in BigQuery. However, I have a custom column created in Google Ads (the quotes per campaign). In the table CampaignStats is this custom column not visible. Therefore, I want to know if there is a possibility to import these custom columns?

I searched in every table that was stored in Bigquery if there were custom columns